# preg_replace url to get id

Tags: php, url, curl, preg-replace

I would like to replace urls in a page with curl in php.

Urls are like;

```
http://www.externalwebsite.com/title-of-the-page-192345.htm
```

I use `$url = preg_replace('~a href="([a-z,.\-]*)~si', '"', $url);`

This gives me the id correctly, but if any other numerical character used in title

for example;

```
http://www.externalwebsite.com/title-of-the-3-page-192345.htm
```

it gives me;

```
3-page-192345
```

output. How can I get the correct id of the page in this situation. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I need to replace urls in the page taken by curl from another site. Urls are like as written above.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init ("http://www.externalwebsite.com/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('#<div class="headline"[^>]*>(.+?)</div>#is', $page, $matches);
foreach ($matches as &$match) {
    $match = $match;
}
$html=$matches[1];   
$html = preg_replace('~a href="([a-z,.\-]*)~si', '"', $html); //NEED TO CHANGE THIS                                         

    echo $html;

?>
```

Html code of the page after curl without any preg_replace is something like that;

```
     <div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
    <div class="title"><a href="http://www.externalwebsite.com/title-of-the-3-page-192345.htm" class="image">
<img src="http://www.externalwebsite.com/d/news/94406.jpg"/></a></div></div>
```

And this html must be something like that after preg_replace command:

```
<div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
        <div class="title"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/read_curl_page.php?id=192345" class="image">
    <img src="http://www.externalwebsite.com/d/news/94406.jpg"/></a></div></div>
```

Comment: You only want the last numbers before the `.htm` ? Need to tweak the RegExp I think... ungreedy pattern match or something like `.*-([0-9])+\.htm`

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_match instead preg_replace

```
<?php

  $matches = array();
  $url ='http://www.mywebsite.com/title-of-the-page-192345.htm';
  preg_match('#http://(.*?)/(.*?)-([0-9]+).htm#', $url, $matches);
  print_r($matches);
  echo $matches[2]; //this will print title of page
  echo $matches[3]; //this will print id of page
  echo $matches[1]; //this will domain
?>
```

It outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => http://www.mywebsite.com/title-of-the-page-192345.htm [1] => www.mywebsite.com [2] => title-of-the-page [3] => 192345 )
```

Preg_replace as its name suggests replace the string you want get some string information. Subpatterns can get these information in `$matches` array. Subpattern for number is `([0-9]+)` which means at least 1 number.

Comment: Thank you but I must change urls to my websites pages, I'm using it to get another sites page content to read on my site. To do this I have to get the spesific id of the pages and replace them to my urls.